# MySQL Connection Persistence or Reconnects? (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

I've created a very basic discord.py bot, which I have connected to a database. When the bot have been idling for a while the connection to the MySQL database times out, resulting in future commands that require the connection to fail.

Would it be better to only open a MySQL connection when a command that requires the connection is used, followed by closing the connection afterwards? Or should I be checking if the connection is still active and if not reinitiate it?

What would be a good approach?

Comment: Are you using an ORM or raw SQL?

Comment: I am using raw SQL

Comment: If you are using raw SQL then define the connection at the bottom of the file after `if __name__ == "main"` block. This will ensure that the connection does not time out. Better still use a library like sqlalchemy or pymysql.

Comment: I will try and look into the ORMs you suggested, thanks!

Comment: cool, let me know if the first option works and i'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Will do! It might take some time to look into SQLAlchemy.